# Itunes search result for app name

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I could search some popular apps in http://www.apple.com/search/. But i can't see my app name here. What should i do get my app name to appear in the search result?

Answer (score 2):

Get a couple of thousand of your closest friends to search using your app's name. Then it will start to pop up in the autocomplete search suggestions. There really isn't any more to it than that.

(You don't really need a couple of thousand, just a few - eventually it will start to turn up).

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the information. Is there any supporting link for this?